# Reset javascript that was jquery-evaluated in an iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, eval

I am using an iframe inside a One-Page-App (javascript), sending JSON object data to it via `postMessage` from the parent document.

Part of that data is evaluated inside the iframe with

```js
js = $.globalEval(javascript_to_be_executed), $(window).load()
```

Now, when I reset the iframe from inside by replacing the `body` and `style` elements by jQuery's `clear()`, the evaluated javascript still seems to be running inside the iframe. I don't want to reload the iframe completely to keep http requests minimal, is there anything I can do to reset the JS in there?

Comment: what is the js that you think is still hanging around?If there are functions you don't want set anymore you can set them to null (same with all the variables). But you won't get rid of them by just clearing out the script tags and such because they are already in memory.

Comment: There may be any kind of javascript in these functions, even $.getScript calls of $(window).load handlers. Can those even be removed from memory?